# Xamarin Android Webview text selection is not working with Custom context menu

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, contextmenu

Xamarin Android Webview is not allowing to select the text when OnCreateContextMenu is overridden to have a new Menu item into the Context Menu.

Also, It does not show the default Menus. So, we want to retain the existing default menus like Copy, Select All, etc. as well when we are adding the new menu.

```
protected override void OnCreateContextMenu(Android.Views.IContextMenu menu)
{
     base.OnCreateContextMenu(menu);
     var item = menu.Add("Add To Notes");
     item.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Have you register the Custom context menu to your `WebView`? Method like this  `RegisterForContextMenu(view)`.

Comment: Actually i'm using the Xamarin.Forms, but I have written the Custom Renderer & tried RegisterForContextMenu(view), but it is giving the same result. The selection is only working when Left Shift Key is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we want to retain the existing default menus like Copy, Select All, etc. as well when we are adding the new menu.

You could override the `onActionModeStarted` method to add a new menu on the default `Menu`. Override this method, you could notifies the `Activity` that an action mode has been started. Here is my code and it works fine ：

```
WebView view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.web);
view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
view.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
view.LoadUrl("https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gFDGWIjIH8LB9AXbwY3QDg");


public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Retain the existing default menus, at the same time adding the new menu :

```
public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{
    IMenu menu = mode.Menu;
    menu.Add("Add To Notes");
    menu.GetItem(0).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(this));
    base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

Set an `ItemClickListerer` on the new `menu` :

```
menu.GetItem(0).SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(this));

public class MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    private MainActivity mContext;

    public MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.mContext = activity;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(mContext, "Hi", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq3Kp.gif).

**EDIT** :

Use this custom `WebView` behavior could be quite simple, you just need add a new menu as I point out above and initialize the `WebView` in `Renderer`, here is my code :

In Xamarin.Forms :

```
public class WebPage : ContentPage
{
    public WebPage()
    {
        var browser = new MyVebView();
        browser.Source = "https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gFDGWIjIH8LB9AXbwY3QDg";
        Content = browser;
    }
}
```

In your `WebViewRenderer` :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyVebView), typeof(MyVebViewRenderer))]
namespace FormsWebView.Droid
{
    public class MyVebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        Android.Webkit.WebView webView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control == null)
            {
                webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                webView.LoadUrl("https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gFDGWIjIH8LB9AXbwY3QDg");

                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Override the `onActionModeStarted` method to add a new menu as I said above :

```
namespace FormsWebView.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "FormsWebView", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
    {
         //...
    }

}

public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
     //...
}

public class MyMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
     //...
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response, we tried this & it is seems to be working well in Xamarin.Android, However, OnActionModeStarted method is not available in WebView Custom Renderer of Xamarin.Forms. So can you please let us know if there is workaround for OnActionModeStarted in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @Shubham Bhosale, actually, `OnActionModeStarted` belong to `Activity` class, you just need to override this method in your Xamarin.Android `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you. We understand that 'OnActionModeStarted ' belongs to 'Activity' class, However we are not sure how to use it from 'WebViewRenderer' in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @Shubham Bhosale, I have update my answer, please check it.